# How to mount a USB device correctly

Tags: mount

There's forums that say you need to specify the mount point

```
Mount /mnt/sdb1
Nano /etc/fstab 
/dev/sdb1  /mnt/sdb/   0   0
Mount -a
```

And others say

```
Mount /media/sdb1

Mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1
```

So my question remains, which is the correct path ?

Comment: Check out `man mount` for the full manual. The basic syntax is `mount -t type device somedir `, where somedir is a mount point.

Comment: Refer also to the Ubuntu wiki: [Mount](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount#Mounting)

Comment: You can only use the mount point if the device is defined in /etc/fstab

Answer (score 1):

## Difference between mount and /etc/fstab approaches

`/etc/fstab` is for permanent automatic mounting (unless you use noauto flag) of devices at boot time. If your USB device will stay plugged in all the time, use this method. Big suggestion,though: use UUID of the device (because device files such as `/dev/sdXY` change and aren't permanent ) as given by `sudo blkid` command. For instance, here's how I mount my second hard drive:

```
# The 400 GB partition on the native HDD
UUID=8e344ab1-5eb5-4e20-becd-4147fffd439f /mnt/HDD ext4 noatime,nodiratime,rw
```

If you intend to mount the USB device on demand, use `mount` command. 
It can be somewhat complicated and requires root privilege.

## Suggested method for mounting

Ubuntu comes with `udisksctl` command, which allows mounting partitions without  need for root privilege. It mounts to specific directory for your user in `/media` directory. Usage is simple:

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda2
```

Or with UUID.

```
udisksctl  mount -b /dev/disk/by-uuid/8e344ab1-5eb5-4e20-becd-4147fffd439f
```

## Additional info

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions